# Why does this code cause memory exhaustion?

Tags: php

There are 2 files on the server. A **1,495 byte** large JSON file and a PHP file containing this code:

```
<?php

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) $data[$i][7] = '1';

?>
```

I get the error below. **Why?**

> **Fatal error**:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted 
>      (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in **/path/to/file/process.php** 
>      on line **4**

(PHP Version 5.4.45)

Comment: Probably because you create an element here: `$data[$i][7] = '1';` every iteration and you very inefficiently count the array in your condition all the time instead of just once: `count($data)`; `for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)` -> `for ($i = 0, $l = count($data); $i < $l; $i++)`

Comment: This will be the accepted answer, if you add it.

Comment: One more question. How does the `$l = ` prevent the for's second expression from being evaluated in the beginning of each iteration? I've thought I'll have to move the whole `$l = count($data)` to the previous line and then simply use `$l` as the second expression.

Comment: You can of course move the assignment outside of the for loop, but the first part (sometimes called initialization part) of the for loop is only executed once, see: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php while the condition, the second part of the for loop, gets executed every iteration to check if the condition still evaluates to TRUE or not.

Comment: Sorry, I've misread your previous answer like this: `for ($i = 0; $i < $l = count($data); $i++)`. That's why I've asked that. But it's clear now, thanks. :)

Comment: You've answered my question as a comment. Could you add it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: I'm fine not in the good mood to write a good answer. You or someone else can answer it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds odd considering that your JSON file is only 1495 bytes. I'm guessing that the content of your file is in *object* form (`{...}`) and that you're running into an infinite loop.

Consider the following program:

```
$json = '{"a":"0"}';
$data = json_decode ($json, true);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
    $data[$i][7] = '1';
```

Every time you run through the loop, an array element is added to the `$data` object, so that `count($data)` is one larger that in the previous round. The count keeps growing so the loop counter can never reach the limit.

The solution is to move the call to `count` out of the loop:

```
$len = count($data);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
    $data[$i][7] = '1';
```

Incidentally, the same problem can also happen with a JSON object in *array* form, with a slightly modified program:

```
$json = '[0]';
$data = json_decode ($json, true);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
    $data[$i+1][7] = '1';  // Note the +1
```

Comment: $data[$i][7] is already in the array, before the loop. (Not in your example, but in my case.) The problem is not the growing length of the array, but the repeated counting (in each iteration), even if the result of the count is the same. So yes, the count has to be moved out of the loop, but for some other reason. Anyway, the idea is good and Rizier123 doesn't want to add his answer (see comments), so I'll accept this.